# Yii using regex for findAllByAttributes

Tags: php, sql, regex, yii

is it possible to check if it has the given string as the substring rather than the whole string in find all by attributes.

```
$posts = Post::model()->findAllByAttributes(array("tag"=>"bad"));
```

suppose there's a post which has a tag breaking,bad I want to be able to find that post also,or as a matter of fact any post which has the sub string "bad" in its string tag like in regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the awesomeness in Yii, use the code below -

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->compare('tag','bad',true,'AND',true);
$posts = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Read up [compare](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail) for more insight on how this works.

Answer (score 2):

You can try as below

```
$match = "bad";

$match = addcslashes($match, '%_'); // escape LIKE's special characters
$q = new CDbCriteria( array(
    'condition' => "tag LIKE :match",         // no quotes around :match
    'params'    => array(':match' => "%$match%")  // Aha! Wildcards go here
) );

$Post= Post::model()->findAll( $q );
```